# What QuestionAnswer is this site running? How can I find out?

Tags: qa

I'm looking to implement a question/answer on my website and came across this one. This guy was complaining in the AdSense forums why he was not accepted. It's very obvious once you start navigating you will notice all of it's content is fake. But I really liked the style but could not compare to any of the open source models or paid ones for that matter.

How can I find out which software is the below site running:

`answersmode(dot)com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **WordPress** but with the [**QAEngine**](https://themeforest.net/item/qaengine-question-and-answer-wordpress-theme/7972399) theme. Only minor customisations have been made beyond that theme, which all appear to be done with the UI that QAEngine provides.

Answer (score 1):

They are running WordPress.  Pretty sophisticated by the look of it.

The hint is in the source code - note the wp-content directory

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.answersmode.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Answers-Mode.jpg" />
```

Yes...it seems like a good idea to spend a lot of time creating a site that will compete with Stack Exchange... :P

Comment: haha true.. no sites can compete with stack when it comes to tech and programming.. whoever thinks that is dum.. but other sites can indeed be bigger as there are others that are bigger in other segments. Now I just got to figure out which theme he is using..  I am also thinking about using Discourse but will see.